# ¿Alinear respecto a un signo/símbolo/caracter en LaTex?

Tags: latex

Tengo el siguiente código para hacer una matriz en LaTex:

```
\begin{eqnarray*}
        \Hess f(\bar{x}) & = &
        \left( \begin{array}{ccc}
        \partial f_{11} & \partial f_{12} & \partial f_{13} \\ 
        \partial f_{21} & \partial f_{22} & \partial f_{23} \\ 
        \partial f_{31} & \partial f_{32} & \partial f_{33}
        \end{array} \right)\\ & = &
        \left( \begin{array}{cccc}
        0 & 1 & 0\\
        1 & 0 & 1\\
        0 & 1 & 0
        \end{array} \right)     
\end{eqnarray*}
```

Que muestra esto:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Sin embargo, eso no es lo que quiero y tampoco lo que debería mostrar, según la referencia que utilicé (y que además probé) el código debería generar lo que mostró anteriormente pero con las matrices alineadas por el simbolo igual '=' como indiqué con los '&'.
También intenté con \begin{align*} lo cual debería dar el mismo resultado (con ecuaciones sencillas, o sea, sin matrices, me resulta el alineamiento).
Entonces, no se si lo que hago esta mal o no está permitido, en todo caso necesito ayuda para realizar eso en caso de poder hacerse.

Comment: Yo acabo de replicar tu ejemplo y me sale bien. Quizás para encontrar el error no baste con el trozo de código que has puesto, sino que sea necesario el documento completo (es decir, qué clase usas y qué paquetes incluyes, por si alguno de ellos fuera el culpable). Intenta crear un "Mínimo Ejemplo Válido" que muestre el problema usando el mínimo de código

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Su sintaxis funciona (cuidado con el header), tanto `eqnarray*` como `align*` deben funcionar como se muestra a continuación.

Pero `align*` es muy preferible a `eqnarray*` ([**fuente**](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/196/eqnarray-vs-align)), esto es muy importante!!

La segunda matriz es `{ccc}`, no `{cccc}`!

Lo siento pero solo hablo italiano y utilicé el traductor de Google :)

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\newcommand{\Hess}{\mathcal{H}}

\begin{document}

\begin{eqnarray*}
  \Hess_f(\bar{x}) & = &
  \left( \begin{array}{ccc}
    \partial f_{11} & \partial f_{12} & \partial f_{13} \\ 
    \partial f_{21} & \partial f_{22} & \partial f_{23} \\ 
    \partial f_{31} & \partial f_{32} & \partial f_{33}
  \end{array} \right)\\ & = &
  \left( \begin{array}{ccc}
    0 & 1 & 0\\
    1 & 0 & 1\\
    0 & 1 & 0
  \end{array} \right)     
\end{eqnarray*}

\begin{align*}
  \Hess_f(\bar{x}) & = %
  \left( \begin{array}{ccc}
    \partial f_{11} & \partial f_{12} & \partial f_{13} \\ 
    \partial f_{21} & \partial f_{22} & \partial f_{23} \\ 
    \partial f_{31} & \partial f_{32} & \partial f_{33}
  \end{array} \right)\\ & = %
  \left( \begin{array}{ccc}
    0 & 1 & 0\\
    1 & 0 & 1\\
    0 & 1 & 0
  \end{array} \right)     
\end{align*}

\end{document}
```

[image: screenshot of output]